# Jquery UI Autocomplete how to send multiple values to serverside?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I am using the Jquery ui autocomplete and I am wondering how do I send multiple values back.

I tried

```
$('#id').autocomplete
            ({
                source: 'MyURL',
                minLength: 2,
                extraParams: { Id: 1 }
            });
```

This does not seem to work.
 [Option for auto complete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions)

**Edit**

I now have this

```
$('#id').autocomplete({      
                source: function (request, response)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'url',
                        data: {
                            term: request.term,
                            Id: 1
                        },
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            response(data);
                        }

                    });
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
```

My controller

```
 return Json("Test",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I also tried

```
 return Content("Test");
```

However now I get  'T', 'E', 'S', 'T' instead of "Test" It is splitting it up for some reason.

Comment: Note that the documentation you're looking at is *not* part of the current jQueryUI autocomplete widget. That documentation is located at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Hmm I don't' see what should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close; The autocomplete widget expects an *array* of candidates back:

> This data should be filtered based on
>   the provided term, and can be in any
>   of the formats described above for
>   simple local data (String-**Array** or
>   Object-**Array** with label/value/both
>   properties)

```
return Json(new[] {"Test"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option for autocomplete to accept multiple values:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

From there you can just send the entire value and split it out on a delimiter (probably the comma) and send each one into an array and work on the values from there.

Comment: I Don't see how there sending multiple values back to the server.

Comment: By sending the multiple inputs as a single string to the server you can have the server split each element apart based on a delimeter, such as the comma. That way you send one thing, but the server can then use the multiple intended values. Most languages have a function such as .split() which does just that. What language are you using on the server?

Comment: I am looking for a better way then this. I rather not do splitting if I need too.

Comment: Did not realize you wanted to utilize JSON. In that case I would got with Andrew Whitaker's response. He is spot on.